# Responsive Navigation with Angular 8 Material Sidenav?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I've seen various implementations [(Including this youtube)](https://youtu.be/Q6qhzG7mObU) that implement a responsive navigation for the Angular Material Sidenav using media queries.

For Angular 8 do we still need custom media queries / CDK Media Queries to implement this, or is there a way to do it declaratively with the component?

My goal is to implement a responsive sidenav similar to the one used in the [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read angular [schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics) you can actually generate responsive NAV bar using Angular Material

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it *completely* with media queries, because the DOM structure between desktop, tablet and mobile are often different.

For example, here is a desktop with a sidebar.

```
+-----+----------+
|     |          |
|     |          |
|     |          |
|     |          |
+-----+----------+
```

The DOM structure might be something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="sidebar"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

When we switch to something like mobile, then the sidebar is often *overlapped* with the `.container` so that the user can open or close the sidebar. The sidebar is shown over top of the container and sometimes has a darkened background overlay.

The DOM structure might be something like this:

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

With *flex* layout you can modify the *order* of DOM elements, but it's not possible to change the DOM structure. The only alternative is to *render* the sidebar twice in the HTML so you show one for desktop and the other for mobile, but itself isn't the best practice.